# Name a .csv file as "From Time1 to Time2.csv" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I want to name a csv file as "From Time1 to Time2.csv".

I am using following codes:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
 
# Note the current time
d1 = datetime.now()


# Note the time after 10 minutes from now
d2 = d1 + timedelta(minutes = 10)


# Create a csv file
with open(d1.strftime("%H_%M_%S.csv"), 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
```

The above codes generates a file "23_01_07.csv" i.e. 23 hrs, 1 min, 7 secs (corresponding to d1 string)

However, I want to name this as "23_01_07_to_23_11_07.csv" i.e. corresponding to both d1 and d2 string.

If somebody could please let me know how do we go about this, I would be very much thankful.

Comment: What are you not sure how to do? Would `d1.strftime("%H_%M_%S") + "_to_" + d2.strftime("%H_%M_%S") + ".csv"` work? Are you aware of string concatenation or formatting in Python?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Random Davis for your valuable feedback. This has worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#datetime.datetime.strftime

In `d1.strftime("%H_%M_%S.csv")`, the .strftime() method returns a string in the format "%H_%M_%S.csv".  So, you want to use this method on d1 and d2, then add the strings together with "*to*" in the middle.

```
from_str = d1.strftime("%H_%M_%S")
to_str = d2.strftime("%H_%M_%S")
filename = from_str + "_to_" + to_str + ".csv"
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @cadvena for your valuable feedback. This has worked

Comment: I made a small tweak to this answer because the `.csv` extension wasn't getting handled properly, now it is.

Comment: Thanks for catching and correcting that Random.